# Обработка результатов поиска

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Пробую выполнить первый проект на js и в ходе выполнения столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами.

Собрал из примеров нужный функционал. Одна из фич должна работать так: человек вбивает в поиск что-то неточное, например, улицу и дом без города, тогда ему выдается несколько вариантов отмеченных на карте. При клике на такую метку надо заменять ее другой или показывать особый балон с кнопкой. Или наоборот, когда результат один, то такую метку надо сразу заменять красной, которая передает адрес дальше.

Проблема в том что я не понимаю где размещаются результаты поиска и как с ними работать. Надо как-то их преобразовать в коллекцию геообъектов?

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init(){

var myPlacemark, metkaCoord, 
suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('searchLine', {boundedBy: [[58.29, 57.47], [56.24, 64.54]]}),
myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
 center: [56.83, 60.60],
 zoom: 9
});


myMap.controls.remove('searchControl');
myMap.controls.remove('trafficControl');
myMap.controls.remove('typeSelector');
myMap.controls.remove('rulerControl');


myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
 var coords = e.get('coords');

 // Если метка уже создана – просто передвигаем ее.
 if (myPlacemark) {
  myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
 }
 // Если нет – создаем.
 else {
  myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
  // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
  myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
   getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
  });
 }
 getAddress(coords);
});

// Создание метки.
function createPlacemark(coords) {
 myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
 return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
  iconCaption: 'поиск...'
 }, {
  preset: 'islands#redDotIconWithCaption',
  draggable: true
 });
}

// Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
function getAddress(coords) {
 myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
 ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
  var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);

  myPlacemark.properties
   .set({
    // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
    iconCaption: [
     // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
     firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
     // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
     firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
    ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
    // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
    balloonContent: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()
   });

   $('#addressFull').text(firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());
   
   
   $('#addressCoordinates').text('');
   $('#addressCoordinates').text(firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates());
   metkaCoord = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates()
   $('#addressRegion').text('');
   $('#addressRegion').text(firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas()[0]);
   $('#addressCity').text('');
   $('#addressCity').text(firstGeoObject.getLocalities()[0]);
   $('#addressDistrict').text('');
   $('#addressDistrict').text(firstGeoObject.getLocalities()[1]);
   $('#addressMcrDistrict').text('');
   $('#addressMcrDistrict').text(firstGeoObject.getLocalities()[2]);
   $('#addressStreet').text('');
   $('#addressStreet').text(firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare());
   
   if (firstGeoObject.getPremiseNumber()) {
    $('#addressHouse').removeClass('text-danger');
    $('#addressHouse').text('');
    $('#addressHouse').text(firstGeoObject.getPremiseNumber());
   } else {
    $('#addressHouse').addClass('text-danger');
    $('#addressHouse').text('номера дома нет');
   }

 });
}


/* Начало поисковой строки*/

$('#searchSubmit').bind('click', function (e) {
 myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
 metkaCoord = null;
 geocode();
});

function geocode() {
 var request = $('#searchLine').val();
 var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(request, {boundedBy: [[58.29, 57.47], [56.24, 64.54]], strictBounds: true});
 myGeocoder.then(
  function (res) {
   myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
   myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange:true}).then(function(){ if(myMap.getZoom() > 16) myMap.setZoom(16);});
  },
  function (err) {
   // обработка ошибки
   alert('Ошибка');
  }
 );
}


/* Заменяем найденный объект на нашу метку */




/* Считаем километры */

$('#buildRoute').bind('click', function (e) {
 console.log(metkaCoord);
 ymaps.route([
  'Екатеринбург, проспект Ленина, 39',
  metkaCoord
 ]).then(
  function (route) {
   myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
   var routeLength = Math.floor(route.getLength() / 1000);
   $('#routeKm').text(routeLength + ' км');
  },
  function (error) {
   alert("Возникла ошибка: " + error.message);
  }
 );
});






}
```

```css
body {font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container my-3">

<h1>Добавление нового объявления</h1>

<p><div class="form-inline"><input type="text" id="searchLine" class="form-control w-50 mr-1" data-provide="typeahead"> <button type="submit" id="searchSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Показать на карте</button></div></p>

<p><div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div></p>

<p id="addressFull">Полный адрес</p>

<table>
<tr>
 <td>Координаты:</td>
    <td id="addressCoordinates"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Область:</td>
    <td id="addressRegion"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Город:</td>
    <td id="addressCity"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Район:</td>
    <td id="addressDistrict"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Микрорайон:</td>
    <td id="addressMcrDistrict"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Улица:</td>
    <td id="addressStreet"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Дом:</td>
    <td id="addressHouse"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p class="mt-5"><button id="buildRoute" class="btn btn-secondary">Посчитать километры от центра</button></p>
<p>Сколько километров от центра: <span id="routeKm">не известно</span></p>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/cLynjk3c/2/

```
function geocode() {
    var request = $('#searchLine').val();
    var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(request, {boundedBy: [[58.29, 57.47], [56.24, 64.54]], strictBounds: true});
    myGeocoder.then(function (res) {
    // !!! В res результаты поиска
    // res.geoObjects - гео-объекты, найденных мест
    if (res.geoObjects.getLength() === 1) {
        createMyPlacemark(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
    } else {
        myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
        myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange:true}).then(function(){ if(myMap.getZoom() > 16) myMap.setZoom(16);});
    }}, function (err) {
        // обработка ошибки
        alert('Ошибка');
    });
}
```

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan - здесь пример на создание пользовательского макета для балуна
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/ - описание гео-объекта